# connecting to virtualbox ubuntu from osx extremly slow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, osx, virtualbox

I am running ubuntu 10.04.x as guest on virtualbox from  osx x 10.10.x host

It works (kind of), but after working a while with it and also after power sleep it can get almost unusable slow.

It looks like an IP-Problem.

My setup:

1. ubuntu has 2 network cards. One over dhcp for internet access over dhcp and one static on vboxnet0 on other subnet
2. added static to /etc/hosts on os x

After booting looks OK re speed:

[image: speed test fresh after booting]

[image: speed test performed several times]

Same with all other tools. But like I said after a while it becomes slow, mounted images over afp or smb get almost unusable.

Looking at dev tools inside chrome I can see that initial connection takes about 10s and DNS Lookup almost 1s.

[image: google chrome dev tools network usage]

Unfortunatelly still a problem. When I continue to work on other apps, the connection breaks down. It stays stable while I am working with it. Doing a ping on the server shows the issue. As soon as I "touch" the virtualbox window, response time gets down to 0.x s
[image: ping on ubuntu server from osx]

Thank you for any help on this!

Comment: Have you tried running `iperf(1)` _after_ it gets slow?

Comment: How much RAM / CPU power have you allocated the Virtualbox OS?

Comment: I just ran iperf again and it shows very different result sets and different ports. Ranging from 150Mbit/s to 25Mbit/s. I am attaching a sreenshot. The VM has 8GByte from 16, 90% CPU power allocated.

Comment: any ideas, somebody? Problem seems to be initial connection